# Hive join query not reading all tables

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

While Running JOIN query in HIVE

```
SELECT c.id_double, o.id_double 
FROM hive_testQ1 c JOIN hive_testQ2 o 
ON (c.id = o.id) limit 3;
```

Output I am getting is:

> 1.2  1.2
>
> 2.2  2.2
>
> 3.2  3.2

but first table has values ***.1*** and second table has values **.2**

No of mapred jobs being launched is only 1.

Why values from only second table are read?`

First Table is:

```js
+------+-----------+---------+------+
| id   | id_double | names   | test |
+------+-----------+---------+------+
|    1 |       1.2 | Frank   |    4 |
|    2 |       2.2 | Jamie   |    5 |
|    3 |       3.2 | Dale    |    6 |
|    4 |       4.2 | Eric    |    7 |
|    5 |       5.2 | Felipa  |    8 |
|    6 |       6.2 | Eric    |    9 |
|    7 |       7.2 | Betty   |   10 |
|    8 |       8.2 | Lena    |   11 |
|    9 |       9.2 | Scott   |   12 |
|   10 |      10.2 | Juanita |   13 |
+------+-----------+---------+------+
```

second table:

```js
+------+-----------+---------+
| id   | id_double | names   |
+------+-----------+---------+
|    1 |       1.1 | Rueben  |
|    2 |       2.1 | Anthony |
|    3 |       3.1 | Nancy   |
|    4 |       4.1 | Sandra  |
|    5 |       5.1 | Ann     |
|    6 |       6.1 | Myra    |
|    7 |       7.1 | Donna   |
|    8 |       8.1 | Ron     |
|    9 |       9.1 | Allen   |
|   10 |      10.1 | Jose    |
+------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Please provide input data

Comment: Why are there only two values, when you ask for 4? Can you show examples of data in the two tables?

Comment: Added sample Input Data ... both tables originally has 1 Lakh Rows

Comment: @PaulF I pasted the wrong query there. I have made edits now.